# Throw error after the retry fails with Angular http.get

Tags: angular, reactjs, rxjs, retrywhen

I'm trying to implement Angular5 http.get with retry.  I wrote

```
http.get<any>('/api/study').retryWhen(
    (errors: Observable<any>):Observable<any> => {
        return errors.flatMap((error: any) => {
            if (error.status  == 500) {
                return Observable.of(error.status).delay(1000);
            }
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }).take(5);
    });
```

This will keep retrying up to 5 times if it gets error 500. However, if it gets 5 failures in a row, then it **returns success** (with null data).  I don't want that. Instead I want it to throw the last error.

I tried to put `.concat(Observable.throw({}))` after the take(), and that works, but it does not give me any information, such as the status code of the most recent error.

How can I get the most recent error after the last retry fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `take(5)` to count the failed attempts and count it yourself using a local variable.

For example you could do this:

```
http.get<any>('/api/study').retryWhen((errors: Observable<any>) => {
    let errors = 0;

    return errors.flatMap((error: any) => {
        if (errors++ < 5 && error.status  == 500) {
            return Observable.of(error.status).delay(1000);
        }
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the errors variable (Observable<any>) with a number (let errors=0)?

Answer (score 3):

`.retryWhen` can only **complete or error** - in both cases, further retries are aborted. [See docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen).

So when you add `.take(5)` you are basically telling it to retry 5 times and **then complete**, at which point it can ONLY complete (and therefore cannot ALSO return an error - it is either one or the other, not both).

So using `.take()` will not solve your issue.

Unfortunately this means you have to keep track of the retry count yourself WITHIN the retryWhen - so for 5 counts you just let it return the error (which will trigger the retry), and finally on count 6 you manually throw an error. You can then catch that final error in a catch block.

Something like this (code not tested but shows the idea):

```
http.get<any>('/api/study').retryWhen(err => {
    console.log('retrying');
    let retries = 0;
    return err
      .delay(1000)
      .map(error => {
        if (retries++ === 6) {
          console.log('retry number ', retries);
          throw error; <- THIS WILL CAUSE retryWhen to complete
        }
        return error; 
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('caught');
    return Observable.of(err);
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log('subscriber');
    console.log(data);
  });
```

As a side note, adding .concat(Observable.throw({})) doesn't solve your problem, because when that fires, your 5 retries are done and hence the retryWhen has completed (ie. returned complete, so no error). This is why the concat cannot throw the last error, because it never received it.